# each, foreach, or map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I've got this code in my PHP :

```
<div class="checkbox-group">
  <input class="selectedProject" type="checkbox" name="project" value="value1">
  [few other inputs]
</div>
```

And this one in my jQuery :

```
$(function({
 var selectedProject = [];
  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
   selectedProject[i] = $(this).val();
  });
)};
```

In the console log, I'm able to get all the checked values like this `["value2", "value4", "value8"]`

Now I want to get all the values one by one to call some function related with the checked box, and can't figure out the best way to get them. Did I need to use `$.each` with keys and values, or is there an another way ?

Comment: Why not just call the function you need from within the `each()` you have right now? Using two loops seems quite redundant.

Comment: And gonna keep the code a bit more DRY. Thanks for pointing it out, I ain't thought about this way at all

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a function directly on the element in $.each:

```
$(function({
  var selectedProject = [];
  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
     // call function here, e.g. on "this"
     // myfunction(this);
  });
)};
```